# China Passport going to Hong Kong then USA via Tokyo

Tags: hong-kong, chinese-citizens

I'm a Chinese passport holder traveling to Hong Kong, going to stay 4 nights in Hong Kong, then going to USA via Tokyo NRT airport on the same day.

I do have USA green card.

Do I have to apply Entry permit to get into Hong Kong ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Hong Kong Immigration Department website](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html), no, you don't because you'll be in transit (holding onward travel tickets) for less than 7 days. Here's the statement:

> Holders of People’s Republic of China (PRC) passports who are in
>   transit through Hong Kong to and from another country or territory may
>   be granted a stay of seven days on each landing without the prior need
>   to obtain an entry permit provided that normal immigration
>   requirements are met, including possession of valid entry facilities
>   for the destination and confirmed onward booking for the overseas
>   journey.

There is more information on [another page](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html) which has general requirements like:

- return tickets or onward travel tickets
- enough money to support yourself for the stay
- no working, starting a business/other business activities, or studying

Answer (score 1):

Both in theory and practice, you're perfectly fine. I do it all the time and was never questioned, as long as I show them my US visa.

Tell them you're going to the US. If they ask you about your visa, show them your green card. You're all set.